# How do you change the turbulence intensity within FLORIS

Tags: floris

I'd like to a run a case where I calculate the power of a small farm for a range of TI values, do I need to edit the JSON input file to do this?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import floris.tools as wfct

# Initialize the FLORIS interface fi (using the example input)
fi = wfct.floris_utilities.FlorisInterface("example_input.json")

# Would now like to loop over TI from 6-15% here and collect powers...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access any of the parameters in the input file programmatically after the input file is loaded. There isn't a one-stop object in the FLORIS framework where all of the parameters live, but the [floris.simulation API docs](https://floris.readthedocs.io/en/develop/source/classes/floris.simulation.html) should give you some guidance.

With that in mind, the best method for iterating over a parameter within FLORIS is the [FlorisInterface](https://floris.readthedocs.io/en/develop/source/classes/floris.tools.floris_utilities.html#module-floris.tools.floris_utilities) object. Once you know where you want to change a parameter in the simulation modules, you can see if there's a helper function in the `FlorisInterface`. Typically, you'll end up modifying one of the inputs to [FlorisInterface.reinitialize_flow_field](https://floris.readthedocs.io/en/develop/source/classes/floris.tools.floris_utilities.html#floris.tools.floris_utilities.FlorisInterface.reinitialize_flow_field) and using that function. [This script](https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/master/examples/example_0005_adjust_floris.py) provides a simple example. I think this is the solution in your case since you can change turbulence intensity through that function call.

When you want to change parameters in other objects like `Wake`, you can extract it from the FLORIS object, make changes, and then supply it back to `reinitialize_flow_field`.

I hope this answers you question!